# Move Wordpress with changed name 'wp-content'

Tags: directory

I've got a problem moving my Wordpress website. 
I did followed the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), but I'm facing some problems because I'll changed the name op my wp-content directory using the [iThemes security](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) plug-in.

I want to move my website from a subdomain to my primary domain. I'll copied all files, changed the links in 'Settings > General', exported the database (to be sure). But after moving all my files are not linked correctly, plug-in and theme files are lost (so said Wordpress) and it's looking for wp-content.

Anyone familiar with this and know how to fix it?

Comment: Third party plugins and themes are off topic, they are better asked about at their developers' sites.

Comment: Well its not specially related to the plug-in. Anyone can rename there wp-content directory name. But thanks though, I will try it there.

Comment: You're supposed to change wp-content on a FRESH install per their directions before uploading any image files and the like. How are you migrating? I'd recommend something that allows you to change DB strings.